# Javascript cursor replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to use an animated cursor in JS. [CSS custom cursors do not animate in most browsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158631/css-animated-cursor/3182672#3182672)

I have heard of people (can't recall who) doing this. They hide the regular cursor (by setting a transparent custom cursor), then create an image that follows the cursor in JS.

Anyone have any better ideas to achieve animated cursors? Is there a jquery plugin that will do this for you? I recall reading a blog that talks about this. Anyone heard of people doing this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Please reconsider this. Websites changing my desktop environment are really annoying and don't add anything to the browsing experience.

I remember the old Comet cursors, god those were horrible.

Comment: @You – Reminds me of [these silly balls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgzQgcVQVTU).

Comment: @You It's not a website, but a rich application. So much for HTML5 replacing flash when it can't even do basic things like animating cursors. Sighs.

Comment: Ugh, I remeber back in the days when Geocities roamed wild on the web and my mouse turned into some stupid bee for no reason that shot sparkles out it's back side...

*I NEVER WISH TO RELIVE THOSE DAYS.*

Comment: @user257493 feel free not to use my site.

Comment: @You Custom cursors can actually be useful in the context of web-based image editing applications (to indicate which tool is being used).

Answer (score 1):

[Have you tried using .ani cursors?](http://www.anicursor.com/webcursor.html) Also see [controlling cursors with css](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/controlling-cursors-with-css-and-creating-cur-files/). I guess you could try to hack this together yourself, but I don't see how you're going to hide the original cursor. Do you really need anything other than the widely supported usualy functionality?

```
li { cursor: text; }
a {cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: I mentioned this in the question. Please read the linked page.

Comment: that user wasn't using .ani cursors. What did you mention?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, that user is me. I added an answer. ani only works on IE. My app doesn't work on IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent cursor, but some in some browsers it will show a black square instead of being transparent.  Also, I have seen a couple examples that use canvas to add effects to the cursor.

A possible example http://jsfiddle.net/5mN9p/ borrowed from this question [Animated image mask following mouse in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250331/animated-image-mask-following-mouse-in-html)

All I added was

```
body{cursor:none;}
```

or possibly

```
canvas{cursor:none;}
```

Which means you can draw anything you want on the canvas at the mouse's coordinates.

Comment: Can you post links to those examples? They might be relevant to this question.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Being several years ago I can't remember the examples I had in mind but here is a link that gives at least an idea of what could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this, but you should be able to create a custom CSS rule (create a class, like `.customcursor`, set the cursor to `url(/path/to/image.png)` and then, on a `setInterval()` cycle between images. Then apply that to your document body.

I haven't a clue how often you can run this, but it should work.