# JS/CSS Library to animate background according to pointer position

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've seen something like this here: http://modularfield.net/tapes

How is this done? Is this some kind of library? Because I could not find anything on the site that would give me a hint, how this is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit buried, but I was able to find the script that they use for that effect. So, here it is: http://mdfield.net/assets/js/geo.js

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with canvas. The animation in the background is probably using something like [PhysicsJS](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/) but will take some coding!

The mask following the mouse pointer is fairly straight forward and was demoed here: [Animated image mask following mouse in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250331/animated-image-mask-following-mouse-in-html)

You will need to change the image though as placekitten.com doesnt seem to be working:

```
img.src = 'http://placehold.it/500/500';
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this tutorial for inspiration by creating this effect on my modularfield.net page: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/09/23/animated-background-headers/

greetings from cologne