# CSS Radial Effect on Image on Hover

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I would like to achieve this effect:
When I hover over an image I would like to apply color in a radial shape on a grayscaled image in a div where the pointer points at[image]

Attached you can find the wanted result and what I currently have!
I also included the code in case you need the logic

```
import university from "../../assets/svgs/university.svg";
import scholarship from "../../assets/svgs/scholarship.svg";
import contactus from "../../assets/svgs/contactus.svg";
import NavigationCard from "./NavigationCard";
import classes from "./NavigationCard.module.css";
import classroom from "../../assets/images/class_hall.jpg";

const Navigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes['navigation-container']}>
      <div className={classes['navigation-inner-container']}>
        <div className={classes["background-image"]}>
          <img src={classroom} alt="classroom" />
        </div>
        <div className={classes["cards-container"]}>
          <NavigationCard
            svg={university}
            navText="Universities"
          ></NavigationCard>
          <NavigationCard
            svg={scholarship}
            navText="Scholarship"
          ></NavigationCard>
          <NavigationCard svg={contactus} navText="Contact Us"></NavigationCard>
        </div>
        <div className={classes['black-cover']}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

CSS

```
.navigation-inner-container {
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.background-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.background-image img:hover{

}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I'm not very clear what effect you want. Are you saying you want the image to be mainly grayscale on hover with just a centrally placed circle being in color? And please include the code you have so far in your question so we can see the relevant HTML structure and related CSS.

Comment: when i hover on the image i want to remove the grayscale only where the pointer is at in a radial shape like the image and i updated the question

Comment: It looks like you're referring to this site. https://flutter.gskinner.com/wonderous/ It's a canvas effect using a mask and tracking the mouse position. This answer here has some pointers on how to get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250331/animated-image-mask-following-mouse-in-html

Comment: yes thats the website ... so i cant apply it with css onHover only :|

Comment: You won't be able to track the mouse position with just CSS, but you could fade colour into the whole image on hover – here's a quick example: https://codepen.io/davidarcus/pen/NWBXGpL

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I now understand what you require. However, to color just an area around the cursor you will need to find the position of the cursor which requires the use of JavaScript. Is that acceptable? (I notice you haven't tagged javascript). Then you can have a pseudo element with the colored background, altering its position as the cursor is moved.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a pen, please check it here - https://codepen.io/nirmalsinghoo7/pen/RwBxWGg
You can generate your required Radial Gradient here - https://cssgradient.io

Here is the code -

```
<div>
<img src="http://i415.photobucket.com/albums/pp236/Keefers_/Keffers%20Animals/evilmonkey.jpg" />
```

```
div{
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: 9;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
      /* filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); Firefox 3.5+ */
      filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
      -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;  
}
div:hover:before{
content:"";
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,233,113,0.5746673669467788) 0%, rgba(136,136,136,1) 100%);
}
```

Output on hover -
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I want to track the pointer and only apply radial around the pointer like [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1969888/dave) said

Comment: Unfortunately this just overlays the image with a slightly opaque radial image, it does not restore the original colors.